# Downsampling algorithms via filter predicates?

Tags: swift, graph, realm, nspredicate

I have results that's are about 50k data points I'd like to graph, but that's more points than there are pixels. So I would like to downsample the 50k records to only about 2,000 records using some technique that is performant and makes sense.

Loading all records into memory than running an algorithm against it takes several seconds to run and the memory shots up to double.

Instead I was hoping to leverage the database to downsample. Is using something like the [largest triangle three buckets algorithm](https://github.com/GuillaumeBeal/LTTB) possible with a filter predicate so I can pass on the heavy lifting to the database to query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LTTB algorithm looks much too complex to compose into an `NSPredicate` query. I don't think that would be possible.

For a query this complex, I think it's definitely best if you pull the data out of the database, and manually process it with your own algorithm.

Realm is very efficient with how it pulls data into memory; the object is only paged in when you touch its properties. If you enclose that 'touch' in an `@autoreleaspool`, you can control when that object is subsequently released, ensuring your memory consumption is kept in an acceptable range.

So for a downsampling algorithm, where you're checking every single Realm object, but then saving a subset of those objects, something like this would be an appropriate implementation:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let dataPoints = realm.objects(DataPoint.self)

var filteredPoints = [DataPoint]()

for index in 0..<dataPoints.count {
    @autoreleasepool {
        let dataPoint = dataPoints[index]
        if LTTBBucket(dataPoint) {
            filteredPoints.append(dataPoint)
        }
    }
}
```

That should take care of the memory consumption at least, but if speed is an issue as well, it might be worth offloading this filtering to a background thread. In this case, you could then simply store the primary key of each data point in an array and pass that back to the main thread when complete.